# GWT JUnit test in NetBeans

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, netbeans, junit

I have written application in GWT using NetBeans. Now I want to test my application with JUnit. I have never used JUnit before but I have basic concept of how it works. Now the question is how do I setup basic Unit test to test some of my GWT Widgets. I found [THIS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cq07247/index.html) simple example but don't know how it can be ran in NetBeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the test file, right click on it and select "Test file", or press Ctrl+F6.

If you are using a Maven 2 project, you can add the [Surefire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/introduction.html) plugin to run all the test automatically when packaging.